# Mirror texture; how to get rid of some unnecessary reflection

Tags: rendering, mirror

I'm rendering a scene with mirrors. Although, the reflection of the 3 hooks (highlighted) that are attached on the mirror are too sharp and clear. IRL it should be extremely subtle that you dont even see the color, but more like a shadow. How should I achieve such effect? Something to change with my mirror texture setting? Thanks[image]
[image]

Comment: They are attached on the mirror but "IRL" the reflection should not be so sharp and clear and the color more like a shadow? But that's not how a mirror works "IRL", here is a photo of a mirror with keyholes and inserted keys: the reflections are quite sharp (execpt for the one in the back out of focus) and the color of the keys is there, too: [mirror with keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzM6A.png) If you don't want sharp reflections, don't set the _Glass BSDF_ to _Sharp_ - this option ignores the _Roughness_ value. Instead switch it to either _Beckmann_, _GGX_ or _Multiscatter GGX_.

Comment: ...and why this ridiculous high IOR of 1000? If this is just to make the glass purely reflective instead of transmissive, a real mirror's reflective surface is a silver or aluminum layer behind the glass, not the glass itself (of course it reflects too, but the main part is the layer behind). So what you need as mirror is a _Principled BSDF_ set to a white _Base Color_ and _Metallic_ to 1, then adjust the _Roughness_ to your liking how sharp you want the reflection to be. To make it more realistic you can put a glass pane in front of it (but with a correct IOR). Or simply take a _Glossy BSDF_.